# Работа с Action Mailer. Вызов экшена рассыльщика

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, action

Добрый день

Есть рассыльщик FeedbackMailer.rb

```
class FeedbackMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'mail@example.com'

  def feedback
    mail(to: 'adr@exmp.ru', subject: 'Very nice email')
  end

end
```

в main'e рендирится вьюха

```
= form_for :mail_body do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Имя"
  = f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Телефон"
  = f.text_area :comment, :placeholder => "Комментарий"
  = f.submit type: "submit", name:"send"
```

в routs.rb прописан путь для обработки события нажатия кнопки

```
post '/', :controller => 'public/main', :action => 'feedback'
```

экшн feedback в контроллере  public/main

```
def feedback
  FeedbackMailer.feedback.deliver_now
end
```

Ошибка

> uninitialized constant Public::MainController::FeedbackMailer

[image: ошибка в контроллере]

Почему mailer не идентифицируется? В чем проблема?

Спасибо

Comment: где лежит и как называется файл мейлера?

Comment: @EugZol app/mailers/FeedbackMailer.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По конвенции, Rails использует `snake_case` для названий файлов. Так что мейлер надо перенести в `feedback_mailer.rb`.